# Resolving Guava dependency when using Gradle 8.5 to download an Android package

Tags: android, gradle

I am using my own build system, and as part of that, I use Gradle (version 8.5) to download packages and their dependencies for Android. This has been working very well, until I attempt to use it to download media3-exoplayer. This is the `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
      url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/'
  }
}

configurations {
  media3_exoplayer
}

dependencies {
  media3_exoplayer 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.3.0'
}

task getDeps {
  doLast {
    copy {
      duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
      from configurations.media3_exoplayer into '..'
    }
  }
}
```

..and this is the error that Gradle emits:

```
Execution failed for task ':getDeps'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':media3_exoplayer'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-android.
     Required by:
         project : > androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.3.0 > androidx.media3:media3-common:1.3.0
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-android:
          - androidRuntimeElements
          - jreRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'androidRuntimeElements' capabilities com.google.collections:google-collections:32.1.3-android and com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-android:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.jvm.environment 'android' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.jvm.version '8' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'jreRuntimeElements' capabilities com.google.collections:google-collections:32.1.3-android and com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-android:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.jvm.environment 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.jvm.version '8' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

As per the getDeps task, it just copies the packages into the folder above the `build.gradle`

ChatGPT has failed to give an answer that works, and it has even suggested asking on Stack Overflow, so here I am :-)

What changes would I need to make to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guava library (a transitive dependency of `media3-exoplayer`) offers two different runtime [variants](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_model.html), one for Android (`androidRuntimeElements`) and one for regular Java (`jreRuntimeElements`).

To resolve the error we have to tell Gradle which one to pick, which we can do by altering the [attributes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_attributes.html) of the requesting configuration (your `media3_exoplayer`).

We can inspect the Gradle metadata in the Guava library [at one of the repositories](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/33.1.0-android/guava-33.1.0-android.module). Here we see the metadata for these two variants differ in the `org.gradle.jvm.environment` entry:

| Variant | `org.gradle.jvm.environment` entry |
| --- | --- |
| `androidRuntimeElements` | `android` |
| `jreRuntimeElements` | `standard-jvm` |

I presume you want the Android one so we need to request libraries with the respective attribute to resolve the clash:

```
configurations {
    register('media3_exoplayer') {
        attributes {
            attribute(
                TargetJvmEnvironment.TARGET_JVM_ENVIRONMENT_ATTRIBUTE,
                objects.named(TargetJvmEnvironment, TargetJvmEnvironment.ANDROID)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Now the dependency should resolve.

Comment: With your change, I get this error:
`> Could not create domain object 'media3_exoplayer' (Configuration)`

Comment: Thank you. A translation error from Kotlin. Now corrected.